# Getting html of current page

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm creating a Firefox addon using jetpack (jpm with node.js) to extend the Firefox developer tools to allow editing the current page's html. (I know this feature already exists; just trying to learn the ropes).

What API do I use to access the current page's HTML? I see that there is a [Debugger.Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger-API/Debugger.Source) but I'm not sure if this is correct. If so, how do I retrieve this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first answer suggests, you can get at the html source using a content script injected the page. For example, here's a very simple approach that uses the tabs module to attach a content script into the current page:

```
const self = require('sdk/self');
const tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

let { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

let button = ActionButton({
  id: "my-button-id",
  label: "Get HTML Source",
  icon: {
    "16": "chrome://mozapps/skin/extensions/extensionGeneric.png",
    "32": "chrome://mozapps/skin/extensions/extensionGeneric.png"
  },
  onClick: (state) => {
    let worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
      contentScript: 'self.port.emit("htmlSrc", {head: document.head.outerHTML, body: document.body.outerHTML});'
    });
    worker.port.on('htmlSrc', (result) => {
      worker.destroy(); // clean up
      let src = "<html>\n"+ result.head + "\n" + result.body + "\n</html>";
      require('sdk/clipboard').set(src, 'text');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct access via SDK is impossible, but you can use [content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_the_Page_Hosted_by_a_Tab) to read and modify the page.